# Is HAML a Better Tool for Experienced Ruby/Rails Developers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

One of the joys of being a new Ruby on Rails student/developer is the constant discovery of new Gems to make my life more fun or easier. Recently, I "discovered" HAML, which appears to be a fantastic tool for making ERB code even more readable than it already is. However, I wonder if it is a good idea for newer developers, like myself, to embrace a tool like HAML early on, or if it would be smarter to hold off until my expertise in plain Ruby / Rails code has matured. My worry, I suppose, is that embracing a tool like HAML too early might impede my full understanding of Ruby through the coding "shortcuts" it offers. What do you experienced coders say?

Comment: Just as a FYI, Perl's Mojo and Mojolicious, which are the equivalent of Padrino and Sinatra, work with HAML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not so much that taking the HAML route will offer you a shortcut, because it's not like HAML is abstracting anything(other than HTML) that you might miss otherwise. HAML is a substitution for ERB, not an abstraction.

With that being said, I think it's completely up to you. If you haven't learned either, I would scope out both and see which one you like better. I know some people who prefer HAML, and some people who prefer ERB.

One other thing to point out is that a lot of code out there is in ERB, so at least getting the general gist of ERB would be helpful to read other code.

Comment: I understand this Gem much more clearly now. Thanks to all who replied, and also, thanks for giving my "noob" question so much constructive help. I think, for now, I will hold off in HAML, though it probably won't be for long. I'm already very experienced in HTML, so it seems HAML will help me improve my code there. With that said, it seems like the comment by @SpyrosP is on target: I can use my time learning more productive things for now, and then focus my attention on beautifying my code later.

Comment: I would agree that you should focus your time on other more important concepts, however choosing HAML vs. ERB (when the time is right) is totally up to you. However you seem to have the answer already :)

Comment: +1 "HAML is a substitution for ERB, not an abstraction." HAML helps get rid of annoying repetition in HTML. The templating capability is so similar to ERB I jump back and forth depending on the project.

Answer (score 3):

I would vote for the latter. It's better to stick to erb in my opinion, at least for now. The main reason is that you can use your time on learning more productive things, such as testing, routing, REST and other more important things.

It's also a matter of taste. Haml is good, but i find erb pretty good as well and just great for what i need to do. I was also thinking of switching to haml for quite some time, but in the end, i would just stick with erb and keep on studying other Rails matters.

You will notice some strong opinions on that subject. For instance, the Rails book by Fernandez solely uses haml, while agile rails uses erb. Find what suits you best, but preferably, do it after some time practicing rails.

Answer (score 2):

HAML is an HTML abstraction. Aside from whitespace concerns, it doesn't change the way you write Ruby per se.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your workflow too.  If you have an HTML guy that will do his HTML in HAML, that will be more useful than taking static HTML and converting it to HAML.  I switched back to ERB from HAML, because it's less work to convert existing HTML to ERB than it is to convert it to HAML.

Comment: +1, this is when I'd stick with ERB and is a project/team decision. For my own work, or if I had someone who was HAML-studly, then I'd use HAML because I think its much cleaner, and results in a better chance of having valid HTML.

Comment: have you used the html2haml command line tool?  The few times I used it, it seemed to work fairly well.

Comment: @cowboycoded - The problem doesn't just lie in converting the HTML, but also if you want you HTML guy to be able to edit your views after they have been implemented, to say, update a class or id on an element.

Comment: I see what ya mean.. makes sense to use erb if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Haml is a great tool and I think you shouldn't worry about using it whatsoever.  It makes your HTML so much more readable.  It doesn't take anything away from the core ruby on rails learning.  Use it and love it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

1. Learn HTML if you don't already know it well
2. Learn how to use erb with HTML.  That might take you 30 minutes.  You just drop ruby code inside <% %> and if you want to output a variable's value you use it with equals sign: <%= %>.  There is really not much to it.  But like others said, you need to at least understand how it works since it is so widely used in view code examples... and it is also used in yaml files.
3. Then spend a few hours learning HAML and use it instead of erb.  Aside from maybe using erb on javascript partials and in yaml files, I never thought twice about using it after learning HAML.

IMO, HAML is way cleaner, less prone to errors and much shorter than writing erb.  HAML closes the tags for you so you dont have to put it in your code, it forces you to write correctly indented code and it has some great shortcuts for adding classes and ids to HTML tags.

I would be interested to hear any use cases where you guys find html.erb better than html.haml.  Like I said, the only place that I don't like to use it is with javascript code... as I find the indentation rules get in the way sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I started using HAML pretty early on and I really like it.  Though like all tools, it has its uses. Some quick points

1. Don't forget you can have both HAML and ERB templates in the same project... just change the extension to change which is used.  You don't have to commit to one or the other.
2. HAML doesn't change the ruby/rails side of the templates... only the representation of the HTML, so it should not hamper your learning.
3. HAML is slower than ERB.  While in most situations this is insignificant (not noticeable to the end user) it is something to keep in mind if you have a partial that is going to be rendered over and over again.

Just some thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

as this was asked 4yrs ago I'll keep my answer short, I just wanted to add that HAML adds that bit of indentaion that makes it even more concise, readable (imo) and very similar to coffeescript and python "styles"

```
- something.map do |x|
  - # ... x
```

vs

```
something.map do |x|
  # ... x
end
```

Yes in every line you have to add `-` but that's because it's a templating engine (and format).

Also to write ruby you have filters so you can just add `:ruby` "blocks".

```
:ruby
  a = 1+1
  multi = "line"
 %html
   %body
     / ...
```

instead of:

```
<%
  a = 1+1
  multi = "line"
%>
<html>
   <body> 
     <!-- ...
```

Because trying ruby without the end statements is something you can do only by installing a patched version of ruby, also haml is already used in the wild and both slim and jade are common too, haml was just the precursor but is more a "close tags" vs "indentation based" style and choice.