# How to create helper for a view which uses HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am working on a web application which must display on the homepage a list of products.
For this I have a ProductsController:

```
     class ProductsController < ApplicationController
       include ProductsHelper
       def index
        @products = Product.last(6).reverse
       end
     end
```

and the corresponding view index.haml:

```
    .main-container.col3-layout
      .main
        .col-wrapper
           .col-main
            .box.best-selling
              %h3 Latest Products
              %table{:border => "0", :cellspacing => "0"}
                %tbody
                  - @products.each_slice(2) do |slice|
                    %tr
                      - slice.each do |product|
                        %td
                          %a{:href => product_path(:id => product.id)}
                            = product.title
                            %img.product-img{:alt => "", :src => product.image.path + product.image.filename, :width => "95"}/
                          .product-description
                            %p
                              %a{:href => "#"}
                            %p
                              See all from
                              %a{:href => category_path(:id => product.category.id)}
                                = product.category.label
        =render "layouts/sidebar_left"
        =render "layouts/sidebar_right"
```

In order to improve the efficiency of this I would like to use helpers, but I have no idea how could I do it without writing HAML code in products_helper.rb file.

Are there any thoughts on how can I accomplish this ?

Comment: I don't think you can without making it ugly.  Why not use partials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some below are for optimizing, others are for cleaning up.

1. [Eager-load your associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) to reduce number of DB queries.

   ```
   @products = Product.includes(:category).all
   @products.each do |product|
     puts product.category.name
   end
   ```
2. Create three-column layout template. Have this include everything in your view template except those inside `.col-main`, and move `yield` in your layout template inside `.col-main`. Remove the layout-specific HAML from your view template.
3. Use `image_tag` and `link_to` view helpers. This is possibly slower than defining the tag yourself, but then again [HAML is known to be slower than ERB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5640090/1547746).

   ```
   %a{:href => '/hyperlink/url'}
     = "hyperlink text"

   = link_to 'hyperlink text', '/hyperlink/url'
   ```
4. [**Take advantage of path generation helpers.**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code)

   ```
   = category_path(:id => @category.id)
   = category_path(@category)
   ```
5. Move markup and code for the product table cell to a view partial.